# Hadith: insects falling in fire

Tags: hadith, source-identification

[In this talk, Abdul Nasir Jangda mentions a hadith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbE5vOmY-90&t=973), where the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) says people are like those flies flying to fire. “I am trying to grab you from your back, but you are slipping right through my fingers,” is how A.N.J. narrates it. Can someone point me to the source of the hadith?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This hadith is in Sahih al-Bukhari. The Prophet (SAW) said:

> "My example and the example of the people is that of a man who made a fire, and when it lighted what was around it, Moths and other insects started falling into the fire. The man tried (his best) to prevent them, (from falling in the fire) but they overpowered him and rushed into the fire. The Prophet (ﷺ) added: Now, similarly, I take hold of the knots at your waist (belts) to prevent you from falling into the Fire, but you insist on falling into it." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/72))

It is also found in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/20), [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/731080), Sahih Ibn Hibban, and Musnad Imam Ahmad.